# Set dimensions of a mesh

Tags: mesh, dimensions

I've set "Meters" as the unit I want to use, with a 1.0000 scale, which means that every square on the grid is 1 meter, right? 
Now, I want to set a cube to be exactly 1.5m tall (for example), how do I do that?

I tried to set the scale in the "scale" section in the object tab, but there's a problem.

This is with scale set to 1 on every direction:

[image]

You see, it takes up 2 squares on the grid for each side. I mean, look at the top side, it takes up 2 squares. If every square is 1 meter, it means that the top side is 2 meters long, right? 
If I want it to be 1 meter long I have to se the scale to 0.5, like this:

[image]

The point is... I've set the scale to 1.0000, as I said, so 1 should be 1 meter...
Did I miss something or this is right?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68678/28015

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's correct.

The *scale* is an arbitrary number which is used to offset the size of the mesh from it's original state. It doesn't refer to the actual size of the mesh, just how much bigger or smaller it is.

I think you are looking for the *dimensions* values in the *properties region*:

[image]

Setting the *dimensions* will set the scale values to the appropriate value to make the mesh a certain size, e.g. 2.5m tall:

[image]

Comment: I didn't notice that section because I was looking at that menu in Edit mode, I switched to Object mode and I found it. Thank you.

Comment: I did not found this option (Dimensions) in v2.77.

Comment: @DanielSantos It's still there. Are you sure you have the right object selected?

Comment: these are all very good but an accurate adjustment of say an extruded part, is not available..

Comment: @DanielSantos Select object -> Choose "Object Mode" -> Press "n" -> In appearing window expand "Transform" tab

Comment: Has this moved in 2.8? Whether in view or in edit mode, I can't seem to find this dimensions section anywhere underneath the scale one.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer it's there in Blender 2.81 for me

Comment: If you're having trouble finding Dimensions under the Scale section, you're probably looking in Object Properties (I had the same problem). Instead, press N while in object mode in the 3d viewport and a panel will open that has Dimensions (but is otherwise similar to the Transform section of Object Properties). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135215/where-did-object-dimensions-go-in-2-8.