# Object dimensions

Tags: dimensions

After setting an object's dimensions, how do you maintain the dimensions, but reset the scale values back to 1.

For example, I set dimensions to 12' x 12' x 1' feet (imperial), and now I'd like to "freeze" the box so that the dimensions remains the same, but the scale is reset to 1.

Comment: I [already](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/set-dimensions-of-a-mesh/44076#comment74117_44076) answered this. `Ctrl` + `A` > *Scale*. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply the scale.
In Object Mode, press CTRL-A, then select "Scale."

This will set the scale to 1, while keeping the dimensions.