# Precise Box creation (migrating from 3d MAX)

Tags: modeling

I'm migrating my primary 3D tool from 3D Max to Blender.
I Just missing to create a precise form. for instance: create a 10x14x12 Box. The For now I'm only able to create an 1x1x1 cube, and them inaccurately move its vertices to a proper position.

Is possible to create a predefined size basic form like this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at some ways here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set dimensions of a mesh](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/set-dimensions-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Sorry, it was not i was looking for. I want to create a mesh based on parameters.

Comment: If you have a particular kind of workflow in mind, try to describe it in the question section, so we can try find something close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A long winded answer.

Most primitive objects (the ones created by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) will display a creation menu on the toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) that will allow you to precisely control dimensions and some variables for that particular object. The same menu is available by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>

Example:

[image]

Note that this original creation menu is only available when you first create the object. Any transformation (move, size, etc) will freeze the object with those settings and pressing undo will not bring back the original menu. Any further transformation will have to be done by editing the mesh.

Now, down to the issue with your box.

Blender does not have options to create [Cuboids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid) with precise dimensions, so you're stuck with creating a cube.

In the case of the cube there is just an option for radius, as is presumed that in a cube all edges will be the same length.

To create a cuboid you need to deform a cube in [Object Mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/modes.html?highlight=object%20mode) to the desired dimensions, using the transform section.

Once you set the size it is very important to **Apply the Transformation** (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

[image]

Please read:

[Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

and

[Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320)

Comment: Perfect Answer.

Comment: Please just add that the user must click into the (+) button (top right of viewport) ir order to see the transform menus, which is closed by default.

Comment: The shortcut for the toolbar is **T**

Answer (score 2):

Migrating from 3DS Max myself, I understand your concerns, yet Moving, Rotating and Scaling in Blender are very precise tools, unless you mean to achieve them in an approximate way, I believe Cegaton already answered your direct question in the best way possible, so I'll include some additional methods in my Answer concerning moving precisely that you mentioned on the side in your question.
In Edit mode, which you access using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can select the face you need to move, press <kbd>G</kbd> "shortcut for move" then the letter associated with the axis you need to move on, for instance <kbd>Z</kbd> to move on the Z axis, then enter the value, keeping in mind the units you are using, so if you are using Metrics, and you want to move the Face / Edge / Vertex 10 cm, enter the value 0.1 followed by Enter, this will move the selected sub-object on Z axis 10 cm in the positive direction, in case you need to move it in negative direction, use the <kbd>-</kbd> before the value, pretty straight forward, the same method works for other Transform tools, for Rotation (in degrees) and scale (in percentage), if you do the Scale in Edit mode, you don't need to apply the scale using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the same method apply in Object mode for Moving / Rotating / Scaling objects, but you need to remember to apply scale, this will become a second nature very soon. 
In Edit Mode, if you need to transform a sub-object using it's normal, you can achieve that by selecting it,  <kbd>G</kbd>  for moving,  <kbd>R</kbd>  for rotating,  <kbd>S</kbd>  for Scale, then  <kbd>Z</kbd>  twice to translate it on normal Z axis, same applies for X and Y axes. Same thing applies in Object Mode if you need to transform the object using it's Local Space.

Keep in mind that Blender automatically assigns the shortcut of pressing axis letter twice <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to Normal if you didn't change the transformation orientation, which is set to Global by default, if you use View for instance, then got back to Global, pressing the axis shortcut twice will assign the View axis, not the Normal axis.

[image: Transformation Orientation]
Another tool concerning precision, and in my opinion, worth alone migrating to Blender, is the measurement options, you can enable few check boxes, to get accurate dimensions of selected faces or edges, angles and even areas 
[image: Measurement options]
Notice in the image above, in the menu, under Mesh Display, I enabled Length for Edge info and Area for Face info, in the 3D View "Viewport" you can see the related info, you don't need to use the tape to measure any more, of course blender has also a Ruler tool in case you need to take dimensions not related to edges or faces. 
Another useful tip, at least I find it useful, is to enable the Enter Edit Mode in the User Preferences Menu under Editing Tab > New Objects 
[image: Enter Edit Mode]
This option will save you a step, in case you edit immediately most of the objects that you create, hence it will automatically enter Edit Mode once the object is created.
Another option you might find useful coming from 3DS Max, is Enabling Auto Perspective option in the User Preferences Menu, under Interface Tab.

[image: Auto Perspective]
This option will convert the view automatically to Orthographic view when you change your view to Front, Side, Top...etc. And it will automatically revert to Perspective mode when you Orbit the view.

Keep in mind to save user settings when you change them if you want to keep the changes whenever you start Blender, also you will need to save Start Up File in File menu, be careful though, this will keep everything you have in the scene saved as start up file, so make sure to do these steps when you have Blender exactly as you want it to start a new document, for instance, if you are working on a project, and you save start up file, then whenever you start a new file, you will have the project there, with all the objects, cameras, lights...etc.

Happy Blending :)